# SSR Hot Reload EADDRINUSE error with Angular v13.3

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

when I try to use SSR hot reload in angular 13, I got this error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::50687

The port number is random everytime I restart it.

Windows 11

Node version: 16.13.2

"@angular/core": "~13.3.3",

"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^13.1.0",

1 months ago I had no problem with all, also at the first building it has no problem, but when i try to save a file, I instantly got this error, I tried everything I found on the internet but nothing worked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxvbC.png

Answer (score 0):

After months without any issue this bug came back. I found a workaround : force an error and save your code so the compilation fails (e.g. a random character in your typescript code), then undo the error, save again, and the hot reload will work.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you already have a server running on such port.

Run:

`npx kill-port 50687` and then you should be able to run your Angular dev-server

Comment: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::51100 the port is random everytime I restart it.

Comment: I can't help you any further with what you've provided us with. Make sure to have a set port that is not already occupied by any other servers or applications. With `angular-cli` you could specify `--port` argument to achieve such task

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled the windows, and now it is good. I think when there was a power outage, some of the windows files were corrupted like kernelbase.dll (I checked it in the event logs), because since that day, the sourctree was not working too. So windows reinstall, or windows repair would help for 100%.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).